# ¿Cómo insertar una lista desplegable en una DataTable?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo la siguiente tabla en html donde inserto un select:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed" id="dataTable" >
                                <thead class="thead-light">
                                    <tr style="text-align:center;">
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th style="display:none;">ID</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Bien a Cargar</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php $numero = 0; foreach($datos['bienes'] as $bienes): $numero=$numero+1;?>
                                    <tr style="text-align:center">
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td style="display:none;">
                                            <?php echo $bienes->idDetalle; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $bienes->Pr_Descripcion.' - '.$bienes->idDetalle; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select class="selectpicker form-control show-tick" data-live-search="true"  title="Seleccionar..." name="<?php echo 'codActFijo'.$numero;?>" id="<?php echo 'codActFijo'.$numero;?>" required>
                                                <?php foreach ($datos['bienes2'] as $bien2) : ?>
                                                    <option value=<?php echo $bien2->codInvActFijo; ?>><?php echo $bien2->Pr_Descripcion.'   -  '.$bien2->codInvActFijo; ?></option>
                                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Intento hacer un POST de los datos seleccionados de la tabla de la siguiente manera con js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
      columnDefs: [ {
          orderable: false,
          className: 'select-checkbox',
          targets:   0
      } ],
      select: {
          style:    'multi', //'os' para seleccion unica 
          selector: 'td:first-child'
      },
      lengthMenu: [[10, 20, 30, -1], [10, 20, 30, "All"]]
  });
  
  $('#vender').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var session = document.getElementById("session").value;
    var solicitud = document.getElementById("solicitud").value;
    
    $('#form').find('input[type="hidden"]').remove();
    var seleccionados = table.rows({ selected: true });
    
    if(!seleccionados.data().length){
        $("#form").submit(); //submiteas el form
      
    }else{
      
      seleccionados.every(function(key,data){
        console.log(this.data());

        $('<input>', {
            type: 'hidden',
            value: this.data()[1],
            name: 'ids[]'
        }).appendTo('#form');

        $("#form").submit(); //submiteas el form
      }); 
    }
});
} );
```

el arreglo llamado ids[] me contiene la informacion seleccionada de la tabla, pero no me devuelve el valor seleccionado del select sino que me retorna el string de la estructura del select.
lo que necesito saber es como puedo obtener el valor que seleccione en el select
estoy utilizando la estructura MVC de PHP para poder hacer el POST. los datos desplegados en el select son traidos desde el servidor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay dos problemas aquí: 1. [DataTable.row().data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) devuelve el contenido de la celda y no valores de elementos de formulario (input, select, etc.). 2. Por la salida en consola, parece que el _select_ es remplazado por una lista o, al menos, eso es lo que guarda _DataTable_ en su caché. Probablemente te sirva la función [to$()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/to$()) para obtener el nodo HTML y buscar el select, algo como: `this.nodes().to$().find('select').val()`

Comment: muchas gracias amigo! es lo que necesitaba. gracias!!